# MediaWiki exhausting PHP's memory limit while uploading file

Tags: php, memory-management, mediawiki

I have a basic MediaWiki installation running on a server. When I try to upload a file, I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 20971520 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 131072 bytes) in /var/www/wiki/includes/BagOStuff.php on line 404
```

The line to which this is referring is:

```
function _serialize( &$data ) {
    $serial = serialize( $data );
    if( function_exists( 'gzdeflate' ) ) {
        return gzdeflate( $serial ); // line 404
    } else {
        return $serial;
    }
}
```

The strange thing is, the upload seems to actually work fine; after the error, navigating to the file's page shown it having been uploaded. Furthermore, the error only occurs when uploading a new file, and not when updating an existing file.

This happens even using quite small image files, and even when PHP's memory limit is increased up to 512M, so a memory problem *per se* seems unlikely. Is gzdeflate having trouble with the serialized file for some reason?

Comment: Could you try bumping up the memory limit again, then forcing the error to happen?  The error message you've provided indicates a *twenty megabyte* memory limit, as opposed to the 512 you've said you increased it to.  Perhaps you forgot to restart the web server software after changing php.ini, or there are multiple php.inis?

Comment: I restarted the web server, and made sure the higher limit had taken effect by putting in a call to phpinfo(). After I found that even 512M didn't fix the problem, I put the lower limit back, which is when this error is from.

Comment: If the upload actually works what is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Which version of MediaWiki are you using, and have you checked your LocalSettings.php?  For 1.15 and earlier, there's a line in there by default that overrides your php.ini:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '20M');
```

And try adding phpinfo() to the end of LocalSettings, not a standalone file, so it shows the status after MW initialization.